# VHDL pulse generator on the press of a button

Tags: vhdl

I want to generate a clock that is high for say .5 secs once I press a button on the FPGA board. At all other times I want the clock to be 0. 
If I press the button again I should again get a .5 sec high time and then again the clock should become 0 and remain 0 until I again press the button.

I want to achieve it using VHDL code.

I have a clock available with me as input whose frequency is 10^8 Hz.

Comment: i want a million dollars.  what have you tried?

Comment: @Mohammad Tanvir: Welcome to Stack Overflow; you may want to spend some time going through the [Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) to learn how this site works.  Note that this question is likely to be voted down or closed since it does not show that you have a fundamental understanding of the subject.

Comment: You're not actually asking a question here.

Answer (score 1):

Start by drawing a block diagram of hardware that will implement your desired function.  Refine each of the pieces until you have something that is quantifiable in some way as hardware (flip-flop, multiplexer, decrementer, "and" gate, zero detect, ...).

If you are stuck with doing your block diagram, think about how you can connect the hardware elements I identified above to create the function.

Once you have your block diagram, if you are still stuck, then do a search on a particular hardware element and you should be able to find a template for it.